# How colorized cells from "green" to "red" in R interface to the DataTables?

Tags: r, dt

There is a great example: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html that allows creating 19 breaks and 20 rgb color values ranging from "white" to "red":

```
library(DT)

# 1. Data
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))

# 2. Create 19 breaks and 20 rgb color values ranging from white to red
brks <- quantile(df, probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
clrs <- round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(brks) + 1), 0) %>%
    {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}

# 3. DT
datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(names(df), backgroundColor = 
 styleInterval(brks, clrs))
```

But how make the same colorizing from "GREEN" to "RED" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could use `colorRampPalette`:

```
ramp <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"))
```

and then select the number of colors from `length(brks)+1`:

```
clrs <- ramp(length(brks)+1)
```

Is this what you had in mind?

[image: datatable with color ramp red to green]